# Matrix coil (serpentine)

Tags: logic

there!

I have a problem in java to generate a matrix like this :

When n= 4

```
{{1   4   5  16},
 {2   3   6  15},
 {9   8   7  14},
 {10  11 12  13}};
```

Matrix shoud contain numbers from 1 to n*n.

I do not want any code, I just want to see how the matrix looks like when n=5 and n=6. 
I have searched on the internet and found just about the spiral matrix, but not this one. 
Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Off course, it is about football!

Comment: Would http://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better site to ask this question? But actually, intuitively, I would guess that to build this for n=5, you just continue the spiral, i.e. you place "17" to the right of "16", and then complete that column downwards with "18,19,20,21", then again leftward (from right to left), "22,23,24,25".

Comment: Thank you! I see 2 identical answers so, this is the answer! Now I can start programming it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the production rule of this matrix is to start in the top left corner, then fill it in the smallest possible loop by starting counter-clockwise, switching between clockwise and counter-clockwise as soon as the boundary is met.

So, for n = 5 it would look like this:

```
{{ 1  4  5 16 17},
 { 2  3  6 15 18},
 { 9  8  7 14 19},
 {10 11 12 13 20},
 {25 24 23 22 21}};
```

And for n = 6 it would look like this:

```
{{ 1  4  5 16 17 36},
 { 2  3  6 15 18 35},
 { 9  8  7 14 19 34},
 {10 11 12 13 20 33},
 {25 24 23 22 21 32},
 {26 27 28 29 30 31}};
```

There are some interesting invariants.
In the first row, every second entry is the square of an even, starting with 4 (2).
In the first column, every second entry is the square of an odd, starting with 1 (1).

The production of the diagonal is `F(n) := n == 1 ? 1 : F(n-1) + 2(n-1)`

Nice stuff, have fun programming with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was thinking that must be a rule with n when is odd and even.